# How to boost convert a LiPo battery to double or triple its voltage, while still charging at original voltage?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have a high resistance load (50k) that I need to pump ~0.2mA across. So basically, I need to put 10V across this load. It's an interesting situation because the voltage needed is quite high but the actual current is quite low.  I would like to be able to charge this device with a 5V microUSB charger. Cost is the primary thing to consider here.

So, I was thinking of using a 5-->10V boost converter to charge some supercapacitors aligned in parallel. I was also thinking of using a D-battery and dropping the micro-USB component. But now I have just figured, because the current needed is so small, that I might be able to boost convert a LiPo battery after charging? Is this possible? I can't find any links online?

If I could double or triple the output voltage of a LiPo battery (to 7-12V) I think this would be ideal, even if the mAh falls to something low like 100 mAh. Does anyone have any experience with something like this that might be useful? Any idea on whether there's a cheaper option here?

Also, how do I determine the LiPo's new battery life based on the boost converter's stats?

Comment: 2 mA thru 50 kOhms is 100 V, not 10 V.  Also current isn't "across" a resistor, it goes thru it.

Comment: Sigh Good eye @OlinLathrop I missed that

Comment: lol ok so it is 10V.. Then again... use a capacitive booster. eg MAX1682 https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/charge-pumps/MAX1682.html

Comment: No wait let me explain.  The current across the load only needs to be 0.2mA, but then I have an opAmp which requires 1mA, so the total current cost is 1.2mA, which I round up to 2mA.

Comment: This question is too much of a moving target, with new constraints coming out of nowhere in the comments.  Then you're not listening to what people are telling you.  The last comment still talks about current "across" the load. Your not ready yet for having others look at your problem since you don't even know what it is.  Giving up and closing, as this seems to be a waste of time for several reasons.

Comment: @OlinLathrop he means 2mA across the load of the doubler, not the 50K. Doubler has more than just the 50K attached. But I agree.. I hate moving target questions too, but at least he is responsive.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Electrical Engineering community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: It's also disrespectful to those who have taken the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to get a larger voltage with minimal load current is to use a capacitive doubler, for example the [MAX1682](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1682-MAX1683.pdf).

[image]

> Their high voltage-conversion
> efficiency (over 98%) and low operating current
> (110μA for MAX1682) make these devices ideal for
> both battery-powered and board-level voltage-doubler
> applications.

However, note the output voltage is dependant on the load current though (see graphs in data sheet) so don't try and draw too much out of it.

Comment: Thanks I will probably accept this. Wouldn't this also work though? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm27313.pdf

Comment: @koampapapa Yes, take this answer as an example only. The TI part will work too but is a boost convertor with more parts and cost. It really depends on how accurate you want that 0.2mA and 10V to be.